# In window phone is there any possibility to mimic the play pause button functionality of music player when screen is locked?

Tags: windows-phone-7, media

is there any possibility to mimic the play pause button functionality of music player. We can use the play pause button even when screen is locked, can i use same functionality in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built-in media controls integration through `BackgoundAudioPlayer`. This is well-documented [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Other than that, you cannot create media playback controls that would be accessible outside the application itself.

Comment: Thanks for the same but the functionality i require is not for media player but just for taking some input from the user when the screen is locked.

Comment: Can't do that on Windows Phone.